# Types of convergence of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Consider the following sequence of random variables defined on the
> probability space $(Ω, F, P)$, where $Ω={0, 1,2, ..., m-1}$, $F$ is the
> collection of all subsets of $Ω$, and $P$ is the uniform distribution over
> $F$.
>
> $$X_n(ω)=\begin{cases} 1/n,& \text{ω=n mod m}\\ 0,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
>
> Does it converges to 0, (a) with probability 1? (b) in mean square?

My understanding is that $X_n(ω)=\begin{cases} 1/n,& \text{w.p. 1/m}\\ 0,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ since it's uniformly distributed.

Therefore, (a) as n goes to ∞, X converges to 0 with probability 1 since 1/n also goes to 0.

(b) $\lim_{x\to∞}E(X_n^2)=\lim_{x\to∞}\frac{1}{n^2m}=0$, X converges to 0 in mean square.

Am I understanding the sequence correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand exactly what you have done, but it is easy to see that $X_n\to 0$ uniformly. As point-wise convergence imply convergence in probability then $X_n\to 0$ in probability also.

For the second part you have that
$$
\operatorname{E}[X_n^2]=\int_{\Omega }X_n^2\mathop{}\!d P= \int_{\{\omega :X_n(\omega )\equiv n\bmod m\}}\frac1{n^2}\mathop{}\!d P=\frac1{n^2}\Pr [X_n\equiv n\bmod m]\leqslant \frac1{n^2}
$$
So $\operatorname{E}[X_n^2]\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is very easy: $|X_n(\omega )| \leq \frac 1 n$ for every $\omega$. This implies that $X_n \to 0$ in probability, almost surely and in mean square.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of the convergence. But I am still confused about the probability. Wouldn't the cardinality be 1 since (n mod m) is always one number? Like, if n mod m=1, card(ω：ω=1)=1 and thus $p_n=1/m$?